# How to see logs of a failing Auth (EasyAuthModule_32/64) when Azure Functions run on a Consumption Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-authentication

I have Azure Functions v2 running on a Consumption plan.

I would like to investigate the reasons why EasyAuth is returning `401 Unauthorized` errors.

As described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#logging-and-tracing), there is a way to investigate such issues by enabling application logging and looking for logs `EasyAuthModule_32/64`.

However, it is not possible to do so when running on a `Consumption` plan because the `Diagnostics Logs` functionality is disabled, as seen in the Azure Portal:

[image: Unable to activate logs]

**Question**

How can I get the logs from `EasyAuthModule_32/64` when running on a Consumption Plan?

**Update**

As of now, when using `Log streaming`, I can only see the logs from my application. I am not sure if I have to enable anything else...

Comment: Just like the note show, did you try the Application Insights?

Comment: Yes, I did. I did not find anything related to that module (-I do get some logs though)... but why a certain request was being unauthorized. I am not sure if I have to change some specific settings in host.config (or else) to see these logs...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, can you try using `Log streaming` to see your error? The option is immediately below `Diagnostic logs` in your screenshot above.

Comment: I tried it several times but nothing is printed except for these lines: `Connecting...
2019-06-18T21:13:28  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2019-06-18T21:14:28  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).` Is there anything I can activate that is not accessible via `Diagnostics Logs`?

Comment: I change the minimum log level from Trace to Debug. I do see my logs now but not the module's...